# The gas provided by remix is too high

Tags: remix, smart-contract-wallets

I try to deploy a smart contract on Arbitrum, and it show this to me

[image]

The gas provided by remix it too high, isn't it? then i switch it to MetaMask

[image]

Meta provided lower gas,then it successed deployed in Arbitrum net, but the contract addres didn't appear in remix interface.
Anyone can give me a explanation for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find the contract address in the Arbitrum Blockchain Explorer by typing in you wallet address and search for the transaction with the contract.

Greetings ~Shadow